# Question about efficiency of an algorithm (Big-O)

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

The efficiency of the algorithm dolt can be expressed as O(n)=n^3.Calculate the efficiency of the following program segment exactly and by using the big-O notation.

```
for (i=1; i <= n+1; i++)
    for (j=1; j < n; i++)
        dolt (...)
```

The second loop is nested but I'm not sure how to format it on the website.

I'm trying to find out if I'm on the right track. My answer was:
$$n\cdot n\cdot  (n^3)= n^5 = O(n^5)$$

Comment: Sorry, but $O(n)=n^3$ is some very strange and probably wrong notation.

Comment: Is it? O(n)=n^3 is how it's written in the question exactly.

Comment: Then your instructor and/or book is using the notation very strangely.

Comment: In the inner loop, shouldn't it be j++ instead of i++?

Comment: Rather perversely, O in O(n)=n^3 is probably not Big-O.

Comment: To format code, select it and use the button `{}` in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since,the second "for" is  nested, the second "for" is implemented $(n+1-1+1) \cdot (n-1+1)=(n+1) \cdot n$ times.

The cost of the  algorithm dolt is expressed as $g(n)=O(n^3)$,so $\exists c>0 \text{ and}  n_0 \geq 1$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$: $g(n) \leq c n^3$

Since,the algorithm "dolt" is also nested, $\text{ cost } \leq Cn(n+1)n^3=O(n^5)$.